# How to Resize An Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I increase or decrase of an Array in Ruby?
 Example I have array sized of 20 and I want to 21th value in it.
 I searched but I didnt find I needed solution. Please I m waiting for your answers. 
Thank you

Comment: you put 21st element into it using one of number of ways. What's the question?

Comment: When reducing the size of an array, how do you decide which element(s) to remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike languages such as C, in Ruby, you don't need to worry about sizing an array to hold its elements. Just set a 21st element like you'd set any other element.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby arrays are dynamic. You can start with an empty array and add elements in it when needed.

```
a = []
a.push('hello')
a.size # 1
a.concat(['hi'])
a.count # 2
a += ['bye']
a.length # 3
a.unshift('morning')
a.size # 4
a[4] = 'end'
a.size # 5
a # ["morning", "hello", "hi", "bye", "end"]
```

Comment: Hey, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

Just add any element at any index, and `nil` will be added where needed :

```
2.3.1 :001 > l = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.3.1 :002 > l[20] = 21
 => 21 
2.3.1 :003 > l
 => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 21] 
2.3.1 :004 > l.first(10)
 => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

If you want to decrease the size, you actually create a new array out of the first `n` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1,2]
array.fill(3, -1, 3)  #=> [1,3,3,3]
```

Comment: Possibly add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are typically unhelpful.